# Adding Text to radio buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am just learning MVC and wanted to create a couple radio buttons so that I can tell what radio button user has picked and what has he typed in the text box for it. So I did this in Razor:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.RadioButton("rb_settingsupdate", "UpdateEmail");
        @Html.RadioButton("rb_settingsupdate", "UpdateQuestions");
        @Html.TextBox("userpassword")
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    }
```

Now in the Controller side I was able to use `[HttpPost]` on my `Index` method and use the `FormCollection` to know which radio button they have chosen and what they have typed.  My problem is I don't know where to put some text for each radio button in Razor? The method `@Html.RadioButton` didn't have parameters for it.

Answer (score 2):

How about just using the html if it is static text?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.RadioButton("rb_settingsupdate", "UpdateEmail"); <label>Update Email</label>
        @Html.RadioButton("rb_settingsupdate", "UpdateQuestions"); <label>Update Questions</label>
        @Html.TextBox("userpassword")
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    }
```

Comment: Within the <label> you could reference the 'name' property so you don't have to add static text. Could also use [attributes] to designate a more user-friendly name - 'has spaces'. But Ben is correct, the radio button html helper is all about the radio button itself at an 'atomic' level. You'll need to use other elements to label it.

Answer (score 1):

I would not do it that way if I were you. Use a model instead. But if you want to do it that way, you may do it like this:

```
Update Email: @Html.RadioButton("rb_settingsupdate", "UpdateEmail");
Update Questions: @Html.RadioButton("rb_settingsupdate", "UpdateQuestions");
```

If you want to use a model, which I encourage, [here](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-radiobutton-radiobuttonfor) is an example.

Comment: @Bohn Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.RadioButton("rb_settingsupdate", "UpdateEmail");
    @Html.RadioButton("rb_settingsupdate", "UpdateQuestions");
    @Html.TextBox("userpassword")
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

In your code above, the second parameter in the RadioButton function (e.g. "UpdateEmail") is the value of the radio button and that is the text that will be displayed.

If you want to display text other that that, use a label.

`@Html.Label`

In terms of best practices for the future once you have a better understanding of MVC, you should make use of view models and use model binding for posting instead of using the form collection. Model binding is a major strength of MVC, you should start leveraging that as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

`RadioButtons` (and `Checkbox` as well) don't have a "Text" property, because the input type `radio` itselfs don't have a text property, as you can see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.radio.html).

Your code will produce something like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="rb_settingsupdate" value="UpdateEmail">
```

So, you have to write a plain Text outside the element, like this:

```
@Html.RadioButton("rb_settingsupdate", "UpdateEmail") <label>Update Email</label>
```

And it will turn into this:

```
<input type="radio" name="rb_settingsupdate" value="UpdateEmail"> <label>Update Email</label>
```

If you have a `Model` with `DataAnnotations` and `Display` properties, you can do in this way:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x=> x.RbSettingsUpdate, "UpdateEmail") @Html.LabelFor(x=> x.RbSettingsUpdate)
```